# Unable to access NIFI REST API using ajax in secured mode

Tags: ajax, rest, apache-nifi

I am trying to access NIFI REST API using ajax call.

I have created access token and passed it using Authorization header.

But it show unauthorized access while accessing.

headers :

```
{Authorization : 'Bearer ' + 'access token here'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieved it by sending Authorization header in beforeSend event like below
 **beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + "access token");} ,**